# Display subcategories from one category

Tags: php, magento

I'm using Magento and I am trying to display all sub categories from one category (42) in an unordered list. I'd also only like to show those subcategories that are active.

I've googled lots of 'solutions', but none seem to work for me. I was wondering if anyone has a definitive answer to this?

Thanks,
Neil

Comment: Want to show us some examples? Would make it more likely that we would help find a solution. A link to a working example would be great (I am assuming this change would be theme related?)

Answer (score 1):

You should use static block.
Somwthing like this:

```
<?php $_categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories(); ?>
<ul>
<?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
<?php if($_category->getIsActive()): ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php echo $_category->getURL() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()) ?></a>
</li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the reply. I actually need to always show specific subcategories, rather than having them change depending on which category is currently being viewed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($parent, $recursionLevel, $sorted)` method, it returns the tree of the subcategories for a particular parent category. **$parent** in this case is category id, **$recursionLevel** is a number of levels for selection subcategories, **$sorted** just indicates whether sort categories or not. Only **$parent** argument is required for the method calling.